# Curly braces annoyance in Windows 7 on MacBook

Tags: windows-7, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2010

I'm just starting out writing C# in MS Visual Studio on a Win 7 partition on my MacBook Pro. Thing is, as a Java programmer I'm used to pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + 8/9 (in OSX) to make curly braces. In Win 7 I need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 7/0. (Swedish keyboard layout) Needless to say, if I'm gonna write in both OS's it's gonna get really annoying =)

Is there any way to customize this kind of "hardcore" keyboard shortcuts in Win 7? Only things I could find was a simple re-mapping utility (Text Services and Input Languages) as well as a custom keyset for UK keyboards.

Also tried a program called Key Mapper. It doesn't seem to be able to add new shortcuts.

Tried another program, G-Hotkey. Again, it only remaps keys and only for specific games/programs. Can't add the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> -8/9 = <kbd>/</kbd> shortcut. Also it gives error messages randomly when I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Comment: When I used to switch between Windows and OSX I made a point of having two different, external keyboards, matching the OS. It still was a major PITA, but switching between the look and feel of the different keyboards made it somewhat easier for me to switch my internal mode.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question... should probably be on SuperUser instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AutoHotkey, it's perfect for remapping keys.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm

Comment: I think that'll solve it. Just need to find the right script to get it to work. Seems to be a problem with more than two simultaneous key presses, but I've posed the question how to do it in their forum.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the keyboard layout under Windows 7 to be the same as you're using in OS X? (What layout are you using in OS X?)

That should get roughly the same layout as you'd be used to under OS X, I'd think. Certainly shouldn't cause any complete differences like the one you ran into...

Comment: In OSX I'm using the Swedish Apple layout, which is also what Windows is using (at least it says so in the locale settings). Still, it's not the same. I do have the BootCamp additions installed.

Near as I can tell from Google, I basically need to use some sort of third party program to get it to work the way I want. Either that, or some sort of advanced configuration plugin for Visual Studio.